# Directx wrappers in C++/Cx for C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, directx

I am trying to develop a C# xaml game for windows phone or windows 8. My main concern is creating the wrappers around DirectX.

From what I understand I have to use C++/Cx to create those wrappers. I was thinking of creating an interface in c# and then implementing it in C++/Cx and then referencing the wrapper class in C# and using it through the interface I declared. Is this possible?

Also, wouldn't this implementation affect performance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I *strongly* suggest that you look into [MonoGame](http://www.monogame.net/). MonoGame is an open-source implementation of the entire XNA framework and runs on Windows, Windows8, Windows Phone 8, iOS, Android, OSX, PS3 & Xbox! Several high-profile, award winning games for a variety of platforms run on MonoGame.

If you want access to the DirectX API specifically, look into [SharpDX](http://www.sharpdx.org/) which already provides a comprehensive .NET class library that wraps DirectX.

Comment: Can I dynamically import and use c# dll's with MonoGame?

Comment: @Alex. Of course. It's all just .NET code. Heck, you can write Mono games in F# if you want ;)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://slimdx.org/

According to their site:

> SlimDX is currently rock solid, covers just about **every multimedia API provided by Microsoft**, and is **stable** enough to be used by commercial projects and companies